# Jquery Cycle-stop after first slide

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery cycle. I need to stop cycle after first slide. i tried to use cycle.stop(); and cycle.destroy(); None works... Can some one help me out.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $('#s2').cycle({
     fx:'scrollUp', 
     speed:  'slow',
     timeout: 2000,
 easing: 'jswing',
 pager:  '#pager', 
 pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index, el) {
 return '<a href="#"> </a>';
        }
});

function getPagerButton(index, targetEl) {
if (index >= slidesCount - 1) {
return "";
    }

return "<span></span>";
    }




</script>
```

Comment: Can you link to the plugin you're using in your question, please.

Comment: Do you want automatic stop, or stop on some event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

**http://jsfiddle.net/R4svX/2/**

code:

```
 $('#s2').cycle({
   after: function (curr, next, opts) {

        console.log(opts.currSlide);

        if(opts.currSlide==1) {
            $('#s2').cycle('pause');
        }
},

     fx:'scrollUp', 
     speed:  'slow',
     timeout: 2000,

 pager:  '#pager',
 pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index, el) {

     return '<a href="#">'+ index+ '</a>';


        }


});
```

So you need to add an after: option/function, get current slide index, and - do what you want.